# <input type = file> not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, input-type-file

I have this tag  and I an using the below code to track file changes. It works in all other browsers but IE9. Can someone please tell me what's going on.

```
$(fileElement).change(function () {
            self.setProgress(0);
            self.file = $(this)[0].files[0]; //This code errors out.
                                       //There is no files object in $(this)[0] but it is there in IE10 and up and Chrome and Firefox.

        });
```

Thanks

Comment: `files` property is not implemented in IE9.

Comment: Is there a workaround for  this.

Comment: Or try this: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Well my switiching to IE10 won't solve the issue for others using our website. I have to support IE9 too and this is an issue that came up at this client.

Comment: So there is no native hml file element that IE9 supports?